# Disconnected in Topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $I$ be an indexing set such that for each $i \in I$, $A_i$ is a subset of $X$ and for all $i, j \in I$, $A_i \cap A_j \ne \emptyset$. If $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$ is disconnected then there is an $i \in I$ such that $A_i$ is disconnected.

My thinking is:

Suppose that no $A_i$ is disconnected, which means $A_i$ is connected for $i\in I$. Since $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ is disconnected, then there are two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cap \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ and $V \cap \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ are disjoint empty sets with $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \subset U \cup V$.
Since $A_i \cap A_j \neq \emptyset$, which means $x\in A_i \cap A_j$, then $x\in U \cup V$. So $A_i \cap U $ and $A_i \cap V$ are non-empty sets.

Is this correct? And I am not sure how to prove they are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following theorem (Kelley 1.21)

> Let $\mathscr A$ be a family of connected subsets of a topological space. Then if no two members of $\mathscr A$ are disjoint, then the union of all members of $\mathscr A$ is connected.

*Proof* : Let $C$ be the union, then if $C$ is not connected, there shall be some subsets $D$ of $C$, such that $D$ is clopen in $C$. Hence for every $A\in \mathscr A$, $D\cap A$ is clopen in $A$. Note that $A$ is connected, either $D\cap A=\varnothing$, which implies that $A\subset D^c$, or $D\cap A=A$, which implies that $A\subset D$. Since every two members of $\mathscr A$ meet, either all members of $\mathscr A$ are subsets of $D$, or all of them are subsets of $D^c$. Hence either $D$ or $D^c$ is void, which implies that $D=C$, and therfore $C$ is connected.

In your argument, since you have supposed that all $A_i$'s are connected, then the union is connected, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. But I want to proof without this theorem (Kelley 1.21).

Comment: @lulu The answer contains a proof of Kelley's theorem. This is nothing else than a proof of your statement *by contraposition*.

Comment: @PaulFrost oh, ok. that's make sense! The other thing is what the mean of the symbol like A? You did $A \in $ ? . what the symbol in ? means?

Comment: $\mathscr A$ [\mathscr A] is a set whose members are connected subspaces of $X$. You can write it in the form $\mathscr A =\{ A_i \mid i \in I \}$ as in your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost could you explain why $D\cap A$ is clopen in A.

Comment: @lulu It follows from the definition of the relative topology, namely a set is open in $A$ if and only if it is the intersection of an open set and $A$.